# What jquery to add so the background of <li> stays highlighted when hovering over subitem(a div)

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, parent

I have a dropdown menu that when the mouse hovers over a link a sub div shows. The script works fine except that when I put my mouse into that subdiv the parent link's background doesnt stay highlighted any longer like it normally does when it's being hovered over. I guess it is the #megamenu that i want to stay highlighted with the associated div. Below is the code please help.

My site, only the about dke dropdown was so far, but it does what i am talking about...

http://www.nestudiosonline.com/test.php

html:

```
<ul id="menu">
        <li class="mega"><a class="dkeorg" href="#">DKE.ORG</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu" id="dave"><a class="links" href="#">ABOUT DKE</a> <div id="aboutdke">div content  </div></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">ALUMNI</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">UNDERGRADUATES</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">MULTIMEDIA</a></li>
        <li class="megamenu"><a class="links" href="#">SHOP DKE</a></li>
      </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul#menu
{
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul# menu li
{
    display:inline;
    position: relative;
    }

ul#menu div {
  display: none;
}

ul#menu li.mega div {
    position: absolute;
}

ul#menu li.hovering div {
  display: block;
}

#aboutdke
{
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    border:0px;
    width:910px;
    height:280px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99999;
    top:164px;
    left:140px;
}

a.links:link
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    float:left;
}

a.links:visited 
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    float:left;
    } 

/* mouse over link */

a.links:hover
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    }   

/* selected link */

a.links:active
    {
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    height:22px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-left:3px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-align:center;
    outline:none;
    background-color:#000;
    float:left;
    }
```

jquery:

Comment: when i click on aboutDKE i am getting a menu is that what you are talking about??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with css.  Change the line

```
a.links:hover
```

to:

```
a.links:hover, .megamenu.hovering a.links
```

in topbanner_back.css.

Basically, you are saying that when a object has a class of 'megamenu' AND 'hovering', that  tags with the class 'links' should look like they do when they are hovered over.